# Why is this local variable amounting to null in Java?

Tags: java, variables, local

My goal is to have a String that stores the contents of a file. I literally ripped the algorithm for reading a file from W3 schools (https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_read.asp) and simply changed a few things.

```
public class Fileparser { 
    
    public void fileParse(String filename) {
        
        
        try {
              File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\(myname)\\Desktop\\" + filename);
              Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
              String output = "";
              while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                output.concat(data);
              }
              myReader.close();
              System.out.println(output);
              
              
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        
    
    }

}
```

In main, of course, I have a Fileparser object that does the method with a file I have on my desktop, but it prints absolutely nothing. I had to wrestle with Java because I am unfamiliar with the scope of local variables. How come output prints nothing, when I am concatenating line by line to it?

Comment: [The `String` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) states that: "*`String`s are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created."* Thus, [`output.concat(data);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) returns a *new* `String`, representing the concatenation. replace this line with `output = output.concat(data);`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `output.concat()` doesn't add anything to the string `output` is pointing at: That's not possible; strings in java are immutable and cannot be changed.

Instead, `concat()` constructs a new string that is the concatenation of the receiver and the parameter, and returns a reference to that. Something as simple as `output = output.concat(data)` would get the job done, but note that concatting like this is incredibly inefficient. Better:

```
try {
              File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\(myname)\\Desktop\\" + filename);
              Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
              StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
              while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                output.append(data);
              }
              myReader.close();
              System.out.println(output);
              
              
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and now let's fix your bugs / styilistic faux-passes:

1. Failure to safely close the resource.
2. Failure to specify charset encoding, making this code OS-dependent (so, a bug, and one you can't test for - quite bad)
3. Very silly exception handling

```
private static final String HOMEDIR = "C:\\Users\\yourname\\Desktop\\";
public String fileParse(String filename) throws IOException {
    try (var s = new Scanner(new File(HOMEDIR + filename, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line = s.nextLine(); line != null; line = s.nextLine()) {
        out.append(line);
    }
    return line.toString(); 
}
```

A method named `parseFile` should obviously be declared to `throws IOException`. It's inherent in what the method is supposed to do.

And then for an encore, use modern API and naming conventions:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

private static final Path HOME = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
public String parseFile(String fileName) {
    return Files.readString(HOME.resolve(fileName));
}
```

Look at how short and pretty that is. one-liner!

NB: The methods in 'Files' use UTF_8 as a default, vs the old stuff that uses the useless 'platform default'.

Answer (score 1):

Change the program like below to make it work as you want.
Here, the behavior of string is when you create a new object it always keeps those objects in the string pool and returns a new one hence you need to assign to the existing string object to concatenate all string objects.

It is always recommended to use StringBuilder when having multiple concatenations.

```
public class Fileparser { 
    
    public void fileParse(String filename) {
    
    
    try {
          File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\(myname)\\Desktop\\" + filename);
          Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
          String output = "";
          while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
           output= output.concat(data);
          }
          myReader.close();
          System.out.println(output);
          
          
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred.");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The return value of "concat" must be used.

Refer to the `.concat` javadocs. It provides the following:

> Examples:
>
> ```
> "cares".concat("s") returns "caress"
> "to".concat("get").concat("her") returns "together"
> ```

It's not a void method. It's a method that returns the result of the concaconated String. So in this case, you should be doing:

```
while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    String data = myReader.nextLine();
    output=output.concat(data);
}
```

Although for better efficiency, I would recommending using a `StringBuilder`, since you are concatenating very often:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    String data = myReader.nextLine();
    str.append(data);
}
myReader.close();
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Or just better off, printing every line inside the loop instead of outside, which will (for the most part) keep the original formatting of the file:

```
Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    String data = myReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(data);
}
myReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `concat`, you’d generally write `+=` to append to a string:

```
output += data;
```

However, both `+=` and `concat` (once fixed as shown in the other answer) inside a loop are *slow*. A much more efficient way is to use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (myreader.hasNextLine()) {
    sb.append(myreader.readNextLine());
}

System.out.println(sb);
// or:
final String output = sb.toString();
System.out.println(output);
```

But there’s actually really no need for this here: just print the lines directly:

```
while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(myReader.nextLine());
}
```